# jquery progressive fade in

Tags: jquery

I'm changing the value of a div when a user clicks on a control and I'm writing this:

```
$('#MyDiv').html(TheText);
$('#MyDiv').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

The problem is that if the user clicks repeatedly on the control that triggers this code, MyDiv eventually disappears. I tried adding .stop() like this:

```
$('#MyDiv').stop().hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

but overall, the MyDiv still disappears.

What do I need to change?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought: why not hide or disable the button that is causing the div to change text and then enable or show that again after the above code segment is executed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with the combination of `fadeIn()` and `stop()`. The solution is to use [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) and set the `opacity` property of a value of `1`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/NhSh6/1/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `fadeIn` fades the element in by animating the element's opacity from 0 **up to its previous opacity**, so if you normally hide an element (default opacity 1), `fadeIn` will fade it in from 0 to 1.

However, if an animation was running before which brought the element to opacity 0.005 for example and you `stop().hide().fadeIn()`, then the element has `opacity: 0.005` when entering the animation, and `fadeIn` will only bring its opacity from `0` up to `0.005`, making it look invisible.

Instead you can do:

```
$('#MyDiv').stop().css({display: 'none', opacity: 1}).fadeIn(1000);
```

which not only hides the element but also resets its opacity back to 1, just before fading in.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/orig/3WsqU/1/)

Comment: +1 for explaining te problem. I was searching for the exact problem, so thank you!